# Как заставить libtorrent не создавать папку с названием?

Tags: c++, torrent

При загрузке торрента через libtorrent (библиотека для C++) создаётся папка с названием торрента, в которую загружаются все файлы. В uTorrent, например, можно убрать галочку "Создать подпапку" при добавлении торрента и всё будет нормально. Как сделать это в libtorrent?